# ‘3704’ Operation is not allowed when the object is closed VB 6.0

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

The following stored procedure works fine in SQL Server, but calling it from VB 6.0 gives me an error

```
Create PROCEDURE spEnvioCorreoCoberturaBoveda
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    CREATE TABLE #tmp(
      iId               INT IDENTITY
    , cAgeCod           VARCHAR(3)
    , cAgeDescripcion   VARCHAR(100)
    )

    DECLARE @viIterador     INT = 1
    DECLARE @viNumRegistros INT = 0
    DECLARE @vcConsulta     NVARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @vcParametros   NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @vcAgeCod       VARCHAR(3)
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    INSERT INTO #tmp(cAgeCod, cAgeDescripcion)
    SELECT cAgeCod, cAgeDescripcion FROM DBComunes.dbo.Agencias WHERE nEstado = 1
    SET @viNumRegistros = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    -- Borrar table
    delete from dbrepstage.dbo.CapSobrantesFaltantesConsolidado
    WHILE @viIterador <= @viNumRegistros
    BEGIN
        SET @vcAgeCod = (SELECT cAgeCod FROM #tmp WHERE iId = @viIterador)
        SET @vcConsulta = ' execute dbcmact'+ @vcAgeCod+'.dbo.CapSobrantesFaltantesConsolidado ' + '''' + @vcAgeCod +''''
        --PRINT @vcConsulta
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @vcConsulta
        SET @viIterador = @viIterador + 1
    END
    drop table #tmp
END
```

VB 6.0

```
Dim sSql As String, nSumaSoles As Currency, nSumaDolares As Currency
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sSql = "DBRepStage.dbo.spEnvioCorreoCoberturaBoveda" & vbCrLf
    
    rs.Open sSql, dbCmact, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
```

> Error: ‘3704’ Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Someone could tell me where I'm failing. Cheers

Comment: Could be that the connection object `dbCmact` is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in line `rs.Open ...` or `rs.Close`?

Just in case, you can try

```
set rs = dbCmact.Execute(sSql)
```

instead of

```
rs.Open sSql, dbCmact, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Comment: Hi. I get on the line: rs.Close

Comment: Maybe you don't need the line `rs.Close`. What's the point with `rs.Close`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a ADODB.Command object, with `CommandType = adCmdStoredProc`, to execute the SP:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
   Set .ActiveConnection = dbCmact  ' Assuming this is a properly initialized ADODB.Connection object
   .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
End With

cmd.CommandText = "DBRepStage.dbo.spEnvioCorreoCoberturaBoveda"
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

And as @MarkL suggested above, make sure your ADODB.Connection opject is properly initilaized

[Added]

As for your `rs.Close` statement, make it a habit of doing something like this:

```
If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    If Not rs.State = adStateClosed Then
        rs.Close
    End If
End If

Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi. If it is open. Because this connection does not use the company, but I think there are problems with many sql statements in vb6.0.

Comment: Nope, there arent, as far as I'm aware. Especially not in the case of a SP, where VB never gets "to see" the actual SQL statements. VB _does_ have problems with supplying/consuming certain (SQL) data types. But as far as pure SQL statements are concerned, VB simply "talks" to the database provider (ADO) and relies on it doing the actual communication with the respective database (engine).